# Como comparar una lista y eliminar duplicados?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, primefaces

Tengo una lista en la cual al editar un registro, agrega uno nuevo en la base de datos, este nuevo registro es prácticamente igual al que  "edite",  pero cambia un id que yo quiero que cambie; al momento de llamar la lista quiero que me reemplace el valor viejo por el nuevo que creo, como puedo hacerlo?

Actualizacion:

aca esta mi bean:

```
package com.em.web.bean;

import com.em.exception.BusinessException;
import com.em.model.dto.CatalogoHijoDTO;
import com.em.model.dto.IpsProyectoIpsDTO;
import com.em.model.dto.ParamSoporteDTO;
import com.em.model.dto.ProyectoDTO;
import com.em.util.AbstractNegocio;
import com.em.web.business.BusinessWeb;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SoporteTipoBean extends BusinessWeb implements Serializable {

private List<SelectItem> itemsContratoCatalogo, selectTiposSoportes;
private List<ProyectoDTO> listaIps;
private String ipsNombre, ipsNit, ipsid;
private ProyectoDTO ipsProyectoipsSelectedDto;
private List<ProyectoDTO> datosFiltrados;
private List<ParamSoporteDTO> lstSoportes;
private List<ParamSoporteDTO> datosParam;
private CatalogoHijoDTO idCatalogoSoporte;
private String tipo;
private Boolean estado;
private Long idSoporteTipo;
private Boolean requerido;
private Boolean opcional;
private Boolean conceptoRecobrable;
private CatalogoHijoDTO idCatalogoTipo;
private CatalogoHijoDTO idCatalogoTipoII;
private Long proyectoIpsId;
private String catalogoHijoValor;
private ParamSoporteDTO datosEditadosDTO;
private ProyectoDTO proyectoIpsSelected;
private ParamSoporteDTO nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO = new 
ParamSoporteDTO();

@PostConstruct

public void init() {

    try {
        itemsContratoCatalogo = 
listItemsCatalogoByNombre("soportes_completitud", Boolean.TRUE, 
Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
        selectTiposSoportes = listItemsCatalogoByNombre("tipos_contratos", 
Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
        itemsTipoAtencion = listItemsCatalogoByNombre("tipos_de_atención", 
Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
        listaIps = ripsEJB.getProyectoIpsByNombre();
        ripsEJB.setEntityManager(AbstractNegocio.ENTITY_RIPS);

        List<String> IpssNames = new ArrayList();
        IpssNames.add("autorizaciones");
        IpssNames.add("tipo_atencion_medicamentos");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AuditoriaBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
    }

}

public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("IPS Seleccionada", 
((IpsProyectoIpsDTO) event.getObject()).getIpsNombre());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    proyectoIpsSelected = ((IpsProyectoIpsDTO) event.getObject());

    try {
        // trae los soportes dependiendo la ips seleccionada
 lstSoportes = ripsEJB.getParametrosSoportesByProyectoIps   
(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId ));



    } catch (BusinessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SoporteTipoBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
    }
}

public void inicializarParametrizacion() {
    nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO = new ParamSoporteDTO();
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws Exception {
    try {
        ParamSoporteDTO editadosDTO = (ParamSoporteDTO) event.getObject();
        if (editadosDTO.getProyectoIpsId().getProyectoIpsId() == -1l) {
            editadosDTO.setIdSoporteTipo(null);
            editadosDTO.setProyectoIpsId(new 
ProyectoIpsDTO(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId()));
            editadosDTO.setEstado(Boolean.TRUE);
//                agrega los nuevos parametros
            editadosDTO = ripsEJB.actualizarParamSoportes(editadosDTO);
//                vuelve a llamar la lista de soportes                
          lstSoportes = 

ripsEJB.getParametrosSoportesByProyectoIps
(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId());

        } else {
            editadosDTO.setEstado(Boolean.TRUE);
            editadosDTO = ripsEJB.actualizarParamSoportes(editadosDTO);                
            lstSoportes = ripsEJB.getParametrosSoportesByProyectoIps
(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId());


        }
     lstSoportes = ripsEJB.getParametrosSoportesByProyectoIps
(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId());                        
        lstSoportes.set(lstSoportes.indexOf(editadosDTO), editadosDTO);

        setFacesMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
COMPLETADO, "Archivo editado éxitosamente!"));

    } catch (BusinessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SoporteTipoBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
        setFacesMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, ERROR, 
"Error interno!"));
    }

}


public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edición Cancelada", 
((ParamSoporteDTO) event.getObject()).getIpsNombre().getIpsNombre());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}           

public void guardarSoporteDocumental() {
    try {
        nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.setProyectoIpsId(new 
ProyectoIpsDTO(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId()));
        nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.setEstado(Boolean.TRUE);

        if (nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.getIdCatalogoTipo().getCatalogoHijoValor().equals("ACTIVIDAD")) {
            nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.setTipo("tipo_atencion");
            nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.setIdCatalogoTipo(nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.getIdCatalogoTipoII());
        } else {
            nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.setTipo("tipo_contrato");
        }

        nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO = ripsEJB.actualizarParamSoportes(nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO);

        if (nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO.getIdSoporteTipo() != null) {
            lstSoportes = ripsEJB.getParametrosSoportesByProyectoIps(proyectoIpsSelected.getProyectoIpsId());

            setFacesMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, INFO, "Parametrizacion creada con exito!"));
        } else {
            setFacesMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, ERROR, "Error no se pudo crear parametrizacion!!"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(SoporteTipoBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        setFacesMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, ERROR, "Error interno!"));
    }
}







public List<SelectItem> getItemsContratoCatalogo() {
    return itemsContratoCatalogo;
}

public void setItemsContratoCatalogo(List<SelectItem> itemsContratoCatalogo) {
    this.itemsContratoCatalogo = itemsContratoCatalogo;
}

public List<SelectItem> getSelectTiposSoportes() {
    return selectTiposSoportes;
}

public void setSelectTiposSoporrtes(List<SelectItem> selectTiposSoportes) {
    this.selectTiposSoportes = selectTiposSoportes;
}

public List<IpsProyectoIpsDTO> getListaIps() {
    return listaIps;
}

public void setListaIps(List<IpsProyectoIpsDTO> listaIps) {
    this.listaIps = listaIps;
}

public String getIpsNombre() {
    return ipsNombre;
}

public void setIpsNombre(String ipsNombre) {
    this.ipsNombre = ipsNombre;
}

public IpsProyectoIpsDTO getIpsProyectoipsSelectedDto() {
    return ipsProyectoipsSelectedDto;
}

public void setIpsProyectoipsSelectedDto(IpsProyectoIpsDTO ipsProyectoipsSelectedDto) {
    this.ipsProyectoipsSelectedDto = ipsProyectoipsSelectedDto;
}

public String getIpsNit() {
    return ipsNit;
}

public void setIpsNit(String ipsNit) {
    this.ipsNit = ipsNit;
}

public String getIpsid() {
    return ipsid;
}

public void setIpsid(String ipsid) {
    this.ipsid = ipsid;
}

public List<IpsProyectoIpsDTO> getDatosFiltrados() {
    return datosFiltrados;
}

public void setDatosFiltrados(List<IpsProyectoIpsDTO> datosFiltrados) {
    this.datosFiltrados = datosFiltrados;
}

public List<ParamSoporteDTO> getLstSoportes() {
    return lstSoportes;
}

public void setLstSoportes(List<ParamSoporteDTO> lstSoportes) {
    this.lstSoportes = lstSoportes;
}

public CatalogoHijoDTO getIdCatalogoSoporte() {
    return idCatalogoSoporte;
}

public void setIdCatalogoSoporte(CatalogoHijoDTO idCatalogoSoporte) {
    this.idCatalogoSoporte = idCatalogoSoporte;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public Boolean getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Boolean estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public Long getIdSoporteTipo() {
    return idSoporteTipo;
}

public void setIdSoporteTipo(Long idSoporteTipo) {
    this.idSoporteTipo = idSoporteTipo;
}

public Boolean getRequerido() {
    return requerido;
}

public void setRequerido(Boolean requerido) {
    this.requerido = requerido;
}

public Boolean getOpcional() {
    return opcional;
}

public void setOpcional(Boolean opcional) {
    this.opcional = opcional;
}

public Boolean getConceptoRecobrable() {
    return conceptoRecobrable;
}

public void setConceptoRecobrable(Boolean conceptoRecobrable) {
    this.conceptoRecobrable = conceptoRecobrable;
}

public CatalogoHijoDTO getIdCatalogoTipo() {
    return idCatalogoTipo;
}

public void setIdCatalogoTipo(CatalogoHijoDTO idCatalogoTipo) {
    this.idCatalogoTipo = idCatalogoTipo;
}

public Long getProyectoIpsId() {
    return proyectoIpsId;
}

public void setProyectoIpsId(Long proyectoIpsId) {
    this.proyectoIpsId = proyectoIpsId;
}

public String getCatalogoHijoValor() {
    return catalogoHijoValor;
}

public void setCatalogoHijoValor(String catalogoHijoValor) {
    this.catalogoHijoValor = catalogoHijoValor;
}

public List<ParamSoporteDTO> getDatosParam() {
    return datosParam;
}

public void setDatosParam(List<ParamSoporteDTO> datosParam) {
    this.datosParam = datosParam;
}

public ParamSoporteDTO getEditadosDTO() {
    return datosEditadosDTO;
}

public void setEditadosDTO(ParamSoporteDTO datosEditadosDTO) {
    this.datosEditadosDTO = datosEditadosDTO;
}

public ParamSoporteDTO getNuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO() {
    return nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO;
}

public void setNuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO(ParamSoporteDTO nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO) {
    this.nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO = nuevaParametrizacionSoporteDTO;
}

public CatalogoHijoDTO getIdCatalogoTipoII() {
    return idCatalogoTipoII;
}

public void setIdCatalogoTipoII(CatalogoHijoDTO idCatalogoTipoII) {
    this.idCatalogoTipoII = idCatalogoTipoII;
}
```

}

Comment: O mas sencillo, quiero eliminar los registros duplicados de una lista, pero el hashset no me ha funcionado, ya que yo quiero escoger cual mostrar en la lista dependiendo de un id especifico, tenia pensado ejemplo: 

if(lista.getProyectoId()!=-1)
{}

Comment: ¿Nos puedes mostrar lo que has intentado?

Comment: lstSoportes = new ArrayList<ParamSoporteDTO>(new HashSet<ParamSoporteDTO>(lstSoportes));    

y en el dto tengo:

Comment: tengo un equals and hashcode en los que selecciono idCatalogoSoporte y idCatalogoTipo, los cuales son los que hacen iguales 2 registros, lo que los diferencia el viejo del nuevo es un id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion, el hashSet si funciona, lo que me faltaba era ordenar los datos en el query de la base de datos (ORDER BY proyecto_id ASC) y me funciono

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta depende del escenario. He planteado dos distintos en esta solución.

### ParamSoporteDTO:

En primera instancia he implementado para este ejemplo, una clase `ParamSoporteDTO` con `proyectoID`, `idCatalogoSoporte`, `idCatalogoTipo` y `nombre`. Según lo que indicas la igualdad de dos objetos se ve determinada si comparten dos de esos ids (override equals)

```
public class ParamSoporteDTO {
    private int proyectoID, idCatalogoSoporte, idCatalogoTipo;

    private String nombre;

    public ParamSoporteDTO() {
        super();
    }


    public ParamSoporteDTO(int proyectoID, String nombre, int idCatalogoSoporte, int idCatalogoTipo) {
        super();
        this.proyectoID = proyectoID;
        this.idCatalogoSoporte = idCatalogoSoporte;
        this.idCatalogoTipo = idCatalogoTipo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }


    public int getIdCatalogoSoporte() {
        return idCatalogoSoporte;
    }

    public void setIdCatalogoSoporte(int idCatalogoSoporte) {
        this.idCatalogoSoporte = idCatalogoSoporte;
    }

    public int getIdCatalogoTipo() {
        return idCatalogoTipo;
    }

    public void setIdCatalogoTipo(int idCatalogoTipo) {
        this.idCatalogoTipo = idCatalogoTipo;
    }

    public int getProyectoID() {
        return proyectoID;
    }

    public void setProyectoID(int proyectoID) {
        this.proyectoID = proyectoID;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + idCatalogoSoporte;
        result = prime * result + idCatalogoTipo;
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ParamSoporteDTO other = (ParamSoporteDTO) obj;
        if (idCatalogoSoporte != other.idCatalogoSoporte)
            return false;
        if (idCatalogoTipo != other.idCatalogoTipo)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=" + proyectoID + ", idCatalogoSoporte=" + idCatalogoSoporte
                + ", idCatalogoTipo=" + idCatalogoTipo + ", nombre=" + nombre + "]";
    }

}
```

### Objeto de prueba:

Para los dos escenarios siguientes, usaré el objeto:

```
[proyectoID=XX, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]
```

Se verá afectado el id del proyecto solamente.

### Escenario 1:

Tienes tu lista `lstSoportes` de `ParamSoporteDTO` y obtienes un nuevo registro `ParamSoporteDTO` que deseas agregar a la lista, reemplazando el antiguo.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestRemDuplicate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<ParamSoporteDTO> lstSoportes = new ArrayList<ParamSoporteDTO>();

        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(1,"nombre1",11,1111));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(2,"nombre2",22,2222));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(3,"nombre3",33,3333));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(4,"nombre4",44,4444));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(5,"nombre5",55,5555));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(6,"nombre6",66,6666));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(7,"nombre7",77,7777));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(8,"nombre8",88,8888));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(9,"nombre9",99,9999));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(10,"nombre10",1010,10101010));
        System.out.println("----------LISTA ORIGINAL-----------");
        lstSoportes.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

        ParamSoporteDTO editado = new ParamSoporteDTO(11,"nombre10",1010,10101010);

        lstSoportes.set(lstSoportes.indexOf(editado), editado);

        System.out.println("\n\n----------LISTA LUEGO DE LA EDICIÓN-----------");
        lstSoportes.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }

}
```

#### Salida 1:

```
----------LISTA ORIGINAL-----------
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=1, idCatalogoSoporte=11, idCatalogoTipo=1111, nombre=nombre1]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=2, idCatalogoSoporte=22, idCatalogoTipo=2222, nombre=nombre2]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=3, idCatalogoSoporte=33, idCatalogoTipo=3333, nombre=nombre3]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=4, idCatalogoSoporte=44, idCatalogoTipo=4444, nombre=nombre4]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=5, idCatalogoSoporte=55, idCatalogoTipo=5555, nombre=nombre5]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=6, idCatalogoSoporte=66, idCatalogoTipo=6666, nombre=nombre6]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=7, idCatalogoSoporte=77, idCatalogoTipo=7777, nombre=nombre7]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=8, idCatalogoSoporte=88, idCatalogoTipo=8888, nombre=nombre8]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=9, idCatalogoSoporte=99, idCatalogoTipo=9999, nombre=nombre9]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=10, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]


----------LISTA LUEGO DE LA EDICIÓN-----------
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=1, idCatalogoSoporte=11, idCatalogoTipo=1111, nombre=nombre1]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=2, idCatalogoSoporte=22, idCatalogoTipo=2222, nombre=nombre2]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=3, idCatalogoSoporte=33, idCatalogoTipo=3333, nombre=nombre3]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=4, idCatalogoSoporte=44, idCatalogoTipo=4444, nombre=nombre4]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=5, idCatalogoSoporte=55, idCatalogoTipo=5555, nombre=nombre5]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=6, idCatalogoSoporte=66, idCatalogoTipo=6666, nombre=nombre6]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=7, idCatalogoSoporte=77, idCatalogoTipo=7777, nombre=nombre7]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=8, idCatalogoSoporte=88, idCatalogoTipo=8888, nombre=nombre8]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=9, idCatalogoSoporte=99, idCatalogoTipo=9999, nombre=nombre9]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=11, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]
```

Como se puede observar, se modifica el último objeto de la lista (antiguo por el nuevo)

### Escenario 2:

El objeto que se agrego a la base de datos se inserta al final de la lista de `ParamSoporteDTO`. Aquí se tratara la lista realizando la siguiente acción:

- Remover la primera instancia del objeto que sea igual al último objeto de la lista.

a modo de prueba, el objeto que hay que reemplazar está en medio de la lista.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestRemDuplicate2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<ParamSoporteDTO> lstSoportes = new ArrayList<ParamSoporteDTO>();

        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(1, "nombre1", 11, 1111));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(2, "nombre2", 22, 2222));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(3, "nombre3", 33, 3333));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(4, "nombre4", 44, 4444));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(5, "nombre5", 55, 5555));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(10, "nombre10", 1010, 10101010));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(6, "nombre6", 66, 6666));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(7, "nombre7", 77, 7777));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(8, "nombre8", 88, 8888));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(9, "nombre9", 99, 9999));
        lstSoportes.add(new ParamSoporteDTO(11, "nombre10", 1010, 10101010));

        System.out.println("----------LISTA ORIGINAL-----------");
        lstSoportes.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));

        lstSoportes.remove(lstSoportes.get(lstSoportes.size() - 1));

        System.out.println("\n\n----------LISTA LUEGO DE LA EDICIÓN-----------");
        lstSoportes.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
    }

}
```

#### Salida 2:

```
----------LISTA ORIGINAL-----------
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=1, idCatalogoSoporte=11, idCatalogoTipo=1111, nombre=nombre1]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=2, idCatalogoSoporte=22, idCatalogoTipo=2222, nombre=nombre2]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=3, idCatalogoSoporte=33, idCatalogoTipo=3333, nombre=nombre3]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=4, idCatalogoSoporte=44, idCatalogoTipo=4444, nombre=nombre4]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=5, idCatalogoSoporte=55, idCatalogoTipo=5555, nombre=nombre5]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=10, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=6, idCatalogoSoporte=66, idCatalogoTipo=6666, nombre=nombre6]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=7, idCatalogoSoporte=77, idCatalogoTipo=7777, nombre=nombre7]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=8, idCatalogoSoporte=88, idCatalogoTipo=8888, nombre=nombre8]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=9, idCatalogoSoporte=99, idCatalogoTipo=9999, nombre=nombre9]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=11, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]


----------LISTA LUEGO DE LA EDICIÓN-----------
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=1, idCatalogoSoporte=11, idCatalogoTipo=1111, nombre=nombre1]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=2, idCatalogoSoporte=22, idCatalogoTipo=2222, nombre=nombre2]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=3, idCatalogoSoporte=33, idCatalogoTipo=3333, nombre=nombre3]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=4, idCatalogoSoporte=44, idCatalogoTipo=4444, nombre=nombre4]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=5, idCatalogoSoporte=55, idCatalogoTipo=5555, nombre=nombre5]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=6, idCatalogoSoporte=66, idCatalogoTipo=6666, nombre=nombre6]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=7, idCatalogoSoporte=77, idCatalogoTipo=7777, nombre=nombre7]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=8, idCatalogoSoporte=88, idCatalogoTipo=8888, nombre=nombre8]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=9, idCatalogoSoporte=99, idCatalogoTipo=9999, nombre=nombre9]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=11, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]
```

Como se observa, se eliminó el elemento duplicado igual al último elemento.

---

Nota: Finalmente pensé en un tercer escenario, en donde los dos registros están en lugares aleatorios de la lista. Pero aquí no puedo decidir de forma lógica cuál es el objeto que va a persistir y cuál será eliminado, a menos que puedas tomar una regla de negocio de proyectoID, pero eso lo desconzco.

Espero haber sido lo más claro posible.

Documentación:

- [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

---

### EDIT:

Según lo que indicas en el comentario, funcionaría con el escenario 1. Un ejemplo de entrada y salida:

```
----------LISTA ORIGINAL-----------
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=11, idCatalogoTipo=1111, nombre=nombre1]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=22, idCatalogoTipo=2222, nombre=nombre2]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=33, idCatalogoTipo=3333, nombre=nombre3]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=44, idCatalogoTipo=4444, nombre=nombre4]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=55, idCatalogoTipo=5555, nombre=nombre5]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=66, idCatalogoTipo=6666, nombre=nombre6]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=77, idCatalogoTipo=7777, nombre=nombre7]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=88, idCatalogoTipo=8888, nombre=nombre8]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=99, idCatalogoTipo=9999, nombre=nombre9]


----------LISTA LUEGO DE LA EDICIÓN-----------
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=11, idCatalogoTipo=1111, nombre=nombre1]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=22, idCatalogoTipo=2222, nombre=nombre2]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=33, idCatalogoTipo=3333, nombre=nombre3]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=44, idCatalogoTipo=4444, nombre=nombre4]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=55, idCatalogoTipo=5555, nombre=nombre5]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=11, idCatalogoSoporte=1010, idCatalogoTipo=10101010, nombre=nombre10]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=66, idCatalogoTipo=6666, nombre=nombre6]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=77, idCatalogoTipo=7777, nombre=nombre7]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=88, idCatalogoTipo=8888, nombre=nombre8]
ParamSoporteDTO [proyectoID=-1, idCatalogoSoporte=99, idCatalogoTipo=9999, nombre=nombre9]
```

Comment: y si el proyecto id de todos fuera -1, y el de el nuevo registro fuera 11, funcionaria tambien?

Comment: si @Juan, con el escenario 1 funciona debido a que compara con idCatalogoTipo y idCatalogoSoporte para buscar el elemento a remplazar. Añadi un ejemplo al final de la respuesta.

Comment: Lo intente pero no me funciona, puede que sea porque soy nuevo programando @Rcordoval